# The space of $k$ differential forms as a Fréchet space

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Given a smooth manifold $M$, can define define seminorms on $\Gamma(U,\bigwedge^kT^{\ast}M)$ for $U$ a coordinate open set by the following: $p^{s}_L(u = \sum_{I}u_I dx_I) = \sup_{x \in M}\max_{|I|=p, \alpha \leq s}|D^{\alpha}u_I(x)|$. But this seminorm is not independent of the choice of the coordinates, then how should I interpret it?

All the references that I found do not mention this matter, but I think it might be the case that different coordinates induce the same topology but I do not see how to show this.

Comment: Wouldn't a metric on TM give one on the associated bundles, for instance the dual and tensor powers of it? Then there's no need to look at coordinate charts. Changes of coordinates, if the set U is precompact, shouldn't change the topology, if you want to use this technique.

Comment: Is it because $U_I$ and $\bar U_I$ under two coordinates differ by a factor of smooth function on $U$, then on a precompact set, the two seminorms are bounded by each other thus equivalent? @DavidRoberts

Comment: @keith: this is true if $M$ is compact

Comment: If I remember correctly, these things are discussed here: http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~crain101/AS-2013/main.pdf

Comment: @Keith that's what I'm thinking. You can get an upper bound for the Jacobian of the change of coordinates over the overlap, and so get an equivalence of seminorms.

Comment: These define the Whitney topology, but don't define a seminorm globally.

Comment: Two remarks. To get the usual Fréchet topology, you would take the suprema over compacta—-there is no reason yours would be finite (see remark by Ben McKay).  Then, if you are prepared to use the closed graph theorem, your result follows automatically from the general principle: there can be at most one Fréchet topology on a space of functions on a given set. Precisely, if you have two such topologies which are finer than pointwise convergence, then they coincide.